# Trace both control and power cables in a factory

Tags: tracking

I am a fresh graduate engineer and tasked with tracing power lines and control cables of equipment in a site to draw its one-line diagram from scratch.

I thought of using a circuit/wire tracer device, like Suretrace for example, but all of those have a maximum energized line voltage rating of 600V, and as I'm being told some power lines could be as high as 1kV.

Any idea what the correct approach might be in this case?

Comment: Do you have physical access to the cables? I don't quite understand your situation.

Comment: There should be cable tags on all cables, and tags in wire  trays. It shouldn't be too hard to find both ends of a particular cable.

Comment: Most of the control cables are overhead in the site and would be hard to get to. Same for some of the power line cables. And the reason I'm tasked with drawing the whole thing from scratch is because the current OLD are unreliable and not everything has a tag.

Comment: "Any idea what the correct approach might be in this case?"  Yes.  Turn the power off and then trace the circuits.

Comment: That is not really viable in an operating industrial plant. I am as perplexed by this task as you are from my question.

Comment: are you certain that the request is not something like asking a rookie pilot to go get a bucket of "prop-wash"?  .... https://www.yourdictionary.com/prop-wash

Comment: you may be able to guess many of them by applying a current transformer to both ends and seeing the same waveform envelope and amplitude

Comment: I don't think a current transformer is going to really help in this case since the source is the same and a lot of loads are identical.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't physically trace the cables individually and you can't  turn anything off you cannot be certain of the circuit so you can only get them to let you turn the power off or put it down as a limitation.